# Problem while developing spring controller, every time I get Ambiguous mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

The error I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map 'tagController' method 
public java.util.List<javaBrains.model.Tag> javaBrains.controller.TagController.getAllTags()
to {}: There is already 'tagController' bean method
public javaBrains.model.Tag javaBrains.controller.TagController.getTag(java.lang.String) mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.assertUniqueMethodMapping(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:621) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$MappingRegistry.register(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:589) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:315) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lambda$detectHandlerMethods$1(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:282) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:280) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.processCandidateBean(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:252) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:211) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:199) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:164) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
```

My code:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;



import javaBeans.repository.AdminUserRepository;
import javaBeans.repository.TagRepository;
import javaBrains.model.AdminUser;
import javaBrains.model.Tag;
import javaBrains.services.TagService;

@RestController
public class TagController {


    @Autowired
    private TagService tagService;

    @RequestMapping("/tags")
    public List<Tag> getAllTags() {

        return tagService.producer();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/tags/{id}")
    public Tag getTag(@PathVariable String id)
    {
        return tagService.getTag(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this class in isolation. You must have another controller somewhere declaring a mapping for `/tags`

Comment: no i didnt it is the only controller class i have

Comment: The exception will tell you what method is already mapped directly after the part you have shown us.

Comment: i have updated the question with the full log i get .... thank u

Comment: Interesting. This should be possible, and your code works for me using the latest version of spring. I wonder whether the behaviour has changed. Can you give the exact version of spring that you're using please?

Comment: version: 5.1.4.RELEASE       it work only when one of the two methods is removed !

Comment: So basically the latest version. The behaviour certainly hasn't changed that recently. One 
weird thing is, `getAllTags` is being processed 2nd and `getTag` has already been mapped. The order shouldn't matter, but I would still expect Spring to go through them in the order in which they're defined. I would put a breakpoint in `detectHandlerMethods` (you can see it in the stack trace) and try to step through to see what is happening.

Comment: As side notes: [Avoid field injection.](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/) `@GetMapping` is clearer than a bare `@RequestMapping`. On a REST controller like this, it's usually better to put the `@RequestMapping("/tags")` on the whole class and then just `@GetMapping` on the collection resource.

Comment: so there I think two options there  first one you create a bean controller with that name on configuration , second one is you setted service name with this controller name , that because spring can not create a controller object or another one there is conflict , or give a name to differently controller

Comment: the getAllTags method  works fine but only if it is the only method in the class @Michael

Comment: did you try @PathVariable("id")?? i really cant see what is wrong.....yisus

Comment: problem was that both of methods uses POST request method .... the problem now how to use POST request for more than one method ?? @Michael

Comment: @evramhany Like I said, it should be possible. I've tested almost your exact code on only a single minor version of Spring ahead of you and it works fine. I've already told you what I'd do: put a breakpoint in `detectHandlerMethods`. Without being able to reproduce it, I can't help you any further, sorry!